# Secure response from Rails to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Please helpe me, I want to show an html element if user is admin else hide the element,

Example:

AngularJS:

```
$http.get('users.json'})
.success(function(data){

    //data user return true and the value true represents admin
    $scope.user = data.user;
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1 ng-show="user">Hello Admin</h1>
```

The problem here, anyone can open firebug or devTools and change user scope value.

Comment: I dont see why it matters: its only client side view, so even if someone changes it and sees 'admin', since the backend wont provide information, its no big deal

Comment: @apneadiving: I'm sure `Hello Admin` is not exactly what he is going to implement in the real app. It is going to be much more. (Admin stuff)

Comment: then what? thats not because you can see the box (view) that you have access to whats inside (secured by the backend)

Comment: but if you have a non secure backend... well... the base of security has always been backend, not frontend. Another example: hiding a link doesnt make it secure

Comment: I don't think the `whats-inside` is protected by the backend here. The attempt is to make a full client side app, and my solution below suggests that OP switches to an architecture where the admin stuff IS protected by the backend :)

Comment: full client side apps must be backed by a server providing data

Comment: Agreed. Empty placeholders would have no meaning for the 'hacker'

Comment: Yes all my templates are public, but there is nothing to do with them, data is provided conditionnaly

Comment: my backend is secured, But I want to hide admin role form front end if user not admin.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in guessing that the above method is not at all secure.

The solution is to either send the local data to the server and get it to return the secure content which is then dynamically injected into the dom.

i.e. Your Admin relevant stuff is not always present on the client side, and only after authentication is it fetched (via AJAX probably) and rendered.

This makes your app a bit more secure.

You might also want to look into the following mechanism for secure authentication on client side apps:

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/